# Why does the "Close votes" review queue have a red dot when empty?

Tags: support, review-queue

I get a red dot displayed in the review queue menu beside the "close votes" queue on Code Review although the queue is empty. On other StackExchange sites I only see this if the queue is very full. Is it correct that the dot is displayed, and if yes what does it mean?

[image: s]

Comment: This is is not specific for Code Review, so this should be asked on the main Meta site. [They are working on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341687/269301), but don't hold your breath. It's going to take a while.

Comment: Ah, I never had this on the other sites, so I thought it was a Code Review specific problem and I didn't look at the main Meta site.

Comment: No, this has been a problem for a while now and they're aware of it. On some sites it's more of a nuisance than others and people have been writing userscripts since *before* that indicator existed as an alternative. It's definitely Stack Exchange wide.